# $L^p$ space in the infinite case

Tags: functional-analysis

The lebesgue space $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ means that all functions, such that:

$$\big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^{\infty}\big)^{1/\infty}<\infty\,\,?$$

Comment: No, obviously not, did someone try to tell you this? It is not very hard to find the correct definition of $L^\infty$, it is basically the space of all bounded functions, up to a.e. equivalence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you have written is not well defined. It is an abuse of the $\infty$ notation. Check out "Walter Rudin: Real and Complex Analysis" for the proper definition and also an interesting problem in the Lp spaces chapter on how L infinity is a "limit" in Lp.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, no.  The reason for the NOTATION $L_\infty$ is that (under the right conditions)
$$
\|f\|_\infty = \lim_{p \to \infty} \|f\|_p
$$
You will find in the older books (say Banach's book) notations like $L_p$ used for $p<\infty$ but something else like $M$ instead of $L_\infty$.